# Glide - resizing images for RecyclerView items:

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, imageview, android-glide

If i understand right, Glide default behaviour is to resize downloaded image according to `ImageView` size before this image will be caching and loading to `ImageView`.

But when should i point actual `ImageView` size (by `override(x, y)`),  and when Glide can calculate it itself?

First of all i'm interested in `ImageView` inside `RecyclerView` item?

Answer (score 2):

Glide works like the following example:

```
Glide  
    .with(context)
    .load(your_image_url)
    .override(600, 200) // resizes the image to these dimensions (in pixel). does not respect aspect ratio
    .into(your_image_view);
```

it will resize it before setting into your imageView

refrence: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-image-resizing-scaling

Comment: Meikiem, i suggest (it follows from comment on your referenced page) that we need "override" option only if app can't measure imageview size without this option....